# Find the Maximum possible condition

Tags: inequality, relations

What is the maximum condition we can mathematically derive from a equation like :

$a - b = 1$ and $|a| + |b| = 1$ where $ a, b \in R$

I was able to conclude intuitively that b has to be negative. Am I right??

Comment: What do you mean by "condition"?

Comment: Any relation on a and b ??.... basically will I be able to prove that b is negative or may be more than this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $b \le 0$, but you can conclude even more.

Hint: Plot the four line segments (one per quadrant in the $ab$-plane) that satisfy $|a|+|b|=1$.